# BlackBerry WebWorks app scrolling

Tags: html, css, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I built an app which loads data dynamically and displays it. On the simulator (Torch 9800, v.6) everything is fine, but on the real device, (same as the simulator), I have a very strange scrolling problem - the scrolling in the app is slow and jumpy. There is no JS or some thread running in the back, so scrolling should be fine. The scroller itself I accomplish by simple `overflow-y:scroll`.

Comment: I have a similar problem on my PlayBook app.  Did you ever solve the scrolling issue?

Comment: I posted the same question on the Support Forum here http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Strange-scrolling-issue/td-p/1530803 but unfortunately was not able to solve by problem. Maybe you can continue the forum thread and get a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it, since you are using html and not jQuery-mobile, I am sure you can "translate" the code to suit your language of choice.

For blackberry Os5, Os6 and Os7 using jQuery-mobile I removed the attribute "data-position: fixed" for headers and footers in pages that required inputting dates, text, e.t.c. and applied this styling:

```
.header {    //.footer
position:fixed;
z-index:10;
top:0;
width:100%;
}
```

for pages that did not neither require scrolling up and down nor inputting fields, I still applied the same styling but added the following attributes in the dynamically injected html  (you do the same for blackberry smartphones that have a virtual qwerty keyboard):

```
 data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false"
```

To translate this to standard css for these properties you can look at any jquery-mobile.css file.

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css and look for the styling applied to `.ui-header-fixed .ui-footer-fixed` for example.

In my case the apps were not as smooth as the iOS and android versions but at least not as jumpy nor as slow as without the workaround.